# How to get the fully resolved path of a symbolic link in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, symlink, python, bash

I have a tangled mess of python installations on my laptop.  I was looking at the executables in `/usr/local/bin` and they are all symbolic links to `../../../Library......`

There's some weird behavior surrounding this.  If I do `ls -lhaG` I see `--->` and the relative path to the right of the symlinks:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    69B Dec  7 22:29 python3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/bin/python3
```

However, I can't seem to get any of the command line tools to resolve that path and display the actual path to python3.  I've found some tidbits here and there regarding use of `pwd -P` and the `find` utility to do this.  The problem is that these don't seem to work on OS X the way that people describe them working on linux (i.e. outputting the full path to the symbolic link).  They just print the symbolic links path for me:

```
FantasticMrFox:bin robert$ pwd -P python3
/usr/local/bin
FantasticMrFox:bin robert$ find `pwd -P` -name python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Answer (score 52):

I think that `pwd -P` and `readlink` are going to be your friends for this task.

"[How can I get the behavior of GNU's readlink -f on a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055671/how-can-i-get-the-behavior-of-gnus-readlink-f-on-a-mac)" is a handy resource.

`pwd -P` only works if you're inside the symlink directory:

```
14:07:13 jason@mac ~ $ cd bin
14:08:08 jason@mac bin $ pwd -P
/Users/jason/Applications
```

`readlink` works by specifying the target (thus it can be used against files):

```
14:09:03 jason@mac ~ $ readlink bin
Applications

14:09:34 jason@mac ~ $ readlink /var
private/var
```

The output of `readlink` appears to be relative to the **parent** of the specified target.

Ex: The parent of `/var` is `/`, so `private/var` is correct, relative to `/`. Per my above example of `bin -> Applications`, both are in my Home Directory, no matter where I run it, the output is the same.

Comment: readlink does not recurse through the case where the symlink points to other symlinks. I would not call that "fully resolved"

Comment: This doesn't appear to work with OP's question about symlinks to things specified with things like `../..`.

Answer (score 26):

This resolves recursively and returns an absolute path:

```
$ python
>>> import os
>>> os.path.realpath("/usr/local/bin/python3")
```

Or the non-interactive version:

```
python -c "import os; print(os.path.realpath('/usr/local/bin/python3'))"
```

Comment: When builtins fail you, resort to scripting... Nice. Definitely works:
>`$ python -c "import os; print os.path.realpath('bin')"`
>`/Users/jason/Applications`.
I symlink ~/bin to ~/Applications in order to have a unified .bash_profile/$PATH across Mac and *nix systems.

Comment: this is great and it works well!  I would mark it as the answer except I also want to know if there's a way to do this in the shell like you can on other *nix systems.

Comment: How do you do it on other *nix systems? Also, Python is installed nearly universally on Linux systems nowadays.

Comment: @vxjasonxv the stuff I found at the time I was messing with this suggested that the `pwd` and `find` commands I talked about in the question resolve the full path on systems other than OS X.  I haven't tested them though.

Answer (score 5):

In zsh:

```
echo /usr/local/bin/python3(:A)
```

Or more robustly, in case there are backslashes in the path:

```
print -lr -- /usr/local/bin/python3(:A)
```

This prints the absolute path to the file with all symbolic links resolved (i.e. it's equivalent to GNU `readlink -f`, not to a plain `readlink`).

Explanation: the parentheses `(…)` at the end of a word surround a list of [glob qualifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers). A colon `:` in the list of glob qualifiers starts a list of [history modifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers). The history modifier `A` turns the given path into an absolute path and resolves all symbolic links.

If this is the `python3` in your `$PATH`, you can save typing with [equals expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#g_t_0060_003d_0027-expansion).

```
echo =python3(:A)
```

Even if you aren't running zsh, you can invoke it just for that.

```
zsh -c 'echo /usr/local/bin/python3(:A)
```

or (putting the history modifier directly on the [parameter expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion))

```
zsh -c 'echo $0:A' /usr/local/bin/python3
```

---

`pwd -P` can work as well, but only for a (symlink to a) directory. `pwd` only prints information about the current directory. It doesn't take an argument. So it's useless for a regular file, and for a directory you need to change into it first.

```
(cd some/where && pwd -P)
```

With `find`, I don't even know what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

GNU coreutils-8.15 added in 2012 a new command-line tool `realpath` that does what you want: it resolves chains of symbolic links and outputs the result as either an absolute (default) or relative path.

Apple does not yet include `realpath` in macOS (they sadly seem to shun all GPLv3 tools), but you can easily install it yourself, e.g. using Homebrew: `brew install coreutils`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this discussion on Stack Overflow is of help: [How to resolve symbolic links in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665/how-to-resolve-symbolic-links-in-a-shell-script)
In particular, please consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665/how-to-resolve-symbolic-links-in-a-shell-script/697552#697552).

Answer (score 1):

There are other answers using a python one-liner, or suggesting to install GNU programs using homebrew so you can have access to `readlink -f` or `realpath`. A recent update to macOS (12.3) has [apparently introduced](https://scriptingosx.com/2022/03/some-cli-updates-in-macos-monterey) `readlink -f` natively as well.

Developing a solution in Bash to do the job across more platforms is a tricky problem, but the following `canonpath` function correctly handles the edge cases that cause some simpler solutions to fail:

```bash
canonpath() (
    # Print absolute canonical path, like GNU's `readlink -f`
    # - target may be symlink, file or directory; path may contain ., .., symlinks
    tgt=${1:?Non-null path required for canonpath}
    [[ -e $tgt ]] || { echo >&2 "target path must exist"; return 2; }

    # resolve symlink(s) at basename (possible chain)
    while [[ -L $tgt ]]; do
        tgt_dir=$(dirname -- "$tgt")
        tgt=$(readlink "$tgt")

        # handle relative symlink and tgt_dir=/
        [[ ${tgt:0:1} == / ]] || tgt=${tgt_dir%/}/$tgt
    done

    _canon_dir() ( builtin cd -P "$1" &>/dev/null && pwd; )

    if [[ -d $tgt ]]; then
        # handle paths like this/is/a/link/..
        printf '%s\n' "$(_canon_dir "$tgt")"

    elif [[ -f $tgt ]]; then
        printf '%s/%s\n' "$(_canon_dir "$(dirname -- "$tgt")")" "$(basename -- "$tgt")"

    else
        echo >&2 "unknown file type"
        return 3
    fi
)
```

Testing examples:

```bash
# use `set -vx` if you want to see the gory details of unwinding the paths
# can also compare against `greadlink -f` if you have installed it with homebrew

canonpath /var
# outputs /private/var on macOS

ln -s ~/Documents /tmp/alink
canonpath /tmp/alink/..
# outputs HOME path as expected

ln -s /etc /tmp/e
mkdir /tmp/a && cd /tmp/a
ln -s ../e b
cd ..
canonpath a/b
# outputs /private/etc on macOS

touch /tmp/f
cd /tmp/a
ln -s ../f
cd ..
canonpath a/f
# outputs /private/tmp/f on macOS
# rm e f a/b a/f && rmdir a
```

#### Handling paths that don't exist

There is a small difference in functionality between the `canonpath` function above and GNU's `readlink -f`, in that `canonpath` explicitly requires that the path must exist. `readlink -f` allows the final path element to be a broken symlink, or simply non-existent. The function could be adapted to accommodate this functionality, but I suggest simply testing for path existence before calling `canonpath`, and passing the parent directory of a non-existent path if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The `-f` flag of `readlink` is introduced in macOS Monterey 12.3 <sup>1</sup>.

So if you're using the version later than or equal to it, `readlink -f` can be used to get the fully resolved path.

From the manpage of `readlink`:

> If the -f option is specified, the output is canonicalized by following every symlink in every component of the given path recursively.

---

<sup>1</sup> According to an answer to the question [Which macOS version introduced "readlink -f"?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/464138/404773).

Answer (score -3):

You may use `readlink -f`. It recurses through all the links. Suppose the link is to a path that is further a link. You would like to have the final absolute path.