# Which macOS version introduced "readlink -f"?

Tags: command-line

The readlink utility on recent macos versions (I'm on ventura) support the "-f" switch, but that has not always been the case. I note, for example, that it's NOT present on 11.6. Which was the first version of macOS to support this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The earliest version where `readlink -f` appears in man pages is macOS Monterey 12.3.

---

The following excerpts were taken from the `stat.1` file for macOS 12.2.

### SYNOPSIS

**readlink** [**-n**] [*file* *...*]

### DESCRIPTION

When invoked as **readlink**, only the target of the symbolic link is printed.  If
the given argument is not a symbolic link, **readlink** will print nothing and exit
with an error.

---

The following excerpts were taken from the `stat.1` file for macOS 12.3.

### SYNOPSIS

**readlink** [**-fn**] [*file* *...*]

### DESCRIPTION

When invoked as **readlink**, only the target of the symbolic link is printed.  If
the given argument is not a symbolic link and the **-f** option is not specified,
**readlink** will print nothing and exit with an error.  If the **-f** option is specified, the output is canonicalized by following every symlink in every component
of the given path recursively.  **readlink** will resolve both absolute and relative
paths, and return the absolute pathname corresponding to *file*.  In this case, the
argument does not need to be a symbolic link.

---

### How to Verify This Answer

The output below is from macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

1. Enter to command `man -w readlink` to determine the file name of the man page to download. The output is shown below.

   ```
   /usr/share/man/man1/stat.1
   ```
2. Enter the command `which readlink` to get the full path to the command. The output is below.

   ```
   /usr/bin/readlink
   ```
3. Use the full path to enter the command `what /usr/bin/readlink`. The output (shown below) can be adapted to find the appropriate `stat.1` file.

   ```
   /usr/bin/readlink
       PROGRAM:stat  PROJECT:file_cmds-287.100.2
   ```
4. Goto [Apple Open Source Releases](https://opensource.apple.com/releases/) to download the appropriate `stat.1` file *for the desired version of macOS*.
5. Enter the command `man ~/Downloads/stat.1` to view the formatted version of the `stat.1` file.

Comment: If you access the Open Source site anyway, you could as well check the source code directly (the man page can also be wrong).

Comment: @nohillside: I suppose if you did not what to trust the man page, you could look at the source code. However, my experience has been source code will often contain so many conditional preprocessor directives that just reading the source code to verify would be difficult. I would instead suggest to actually compile and link to get an executable. Personally, I would verify the man page by downloading the appropriate version of macOS and install in a virtual machine. Of course, being able to create an executable or virtual machine depends on which model/year Macs you have at your disposal.

Comment: The first build to include `-f` is [`file_cmds-353.100.22`](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/file_cmds/blob/file_cmds-353.100.22/stat/stat.c), better known as  macOS 12.3 :-) OTOH, the `readlink` functionality was present long before there was a man page for it (already in Tiger).

Comment: @nohillside:  I assume you mean `readlink`. I am not sure if you are saying Tiger has or does not have a man page for `readlink`. I downloaded `stat.1` for OS X Tiger 10.4 and found `readlink`. So I think there is a man page in Tiger for `readlink`.

Comment: I meant readlink. And indeed, while the Tiger source code doesn't have readlink.1 the Makefile creates it out of stat.1.